# Standalone Component & Material Dialog: Different same service instance after migration

Tags: angular, angular-material

Facing an issue with standalone components using Material dialog.

**Here's the flow:**

1. Standalone Component A: Injects and uses SomeService.
2. Standalone Component A opens Material Dialog:

- Dialog component (Component B) also uses SomeService.

Expected: All components (A and B) should access the same SomeService instance.
Actual: Previously both components were imported on one module with provided service. After migrating to standalone components, SomeService appears to have different instances in each component. It is provided in both components. Gives error if I don't provide it in dialog component.
[image]

Tried different ways to fix this with no success.

Comment: You need to provide your startup/module code that references these services and components for us to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67491375/13727635) fixed my issue.

1. Inject ViewContainerRef into your host component: In the component
   that opens the dialog (Component A), you need to inject
   ViewContainerRef. This is typically done in the constructor of the
   component.
2. Modify the open method: When opening the dialog using MatDialog, pass    the viewContainerRef property within the
   MatDialogConfig object. This    step links the dialog component's
   (Component B) change detection and    dependency injection to that
   of the host component.
3. Remove redundant providers: Since the same instance of SomeService is    now available in both components, you do not need
   to provide it again    in the dialog component (Component B).

Answer (score 0):

1. A service provide in root you **NOT** include in providers
2. If you want "belong" only a route see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#providing-services-to-a-subset-of-routes)